# call modal and show it with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which I get from ajax, and I need to show in my page.

In index.html

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="buttonclass" type="button" onclick="getMyModal()">
          Aceptar
        </button>
```

getMyModal():

```
function getMyModal (){


var request = { myrequest};

$.ajax({
    url : "myUrl",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data : {
        "requestData": JSON.stringify(request) 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 

        var myModal = response.myModal;
        $(myModal).appendTo('body');

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }   
});
```

}

it doesnt append the code to 'body' page.

how can I do this?

Comment: You need to show the appended `modal`. Are you sure you are getting into `success`?

Comment: it works! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How would a `javascript` variable will `appendTo DOM` instead try this:

```
$( "#test" ).append( myModal );
or
$( 'body' ).append( myModal );
```

Add a `div` to `body` with `id test` or anything meaningful. Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/kipiciyuca/edit?html,js,output).